# How is "sakan" (盛ん) really pronunced?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm learning this word and the softwares I'm using (the package JLPT N4 Vocabulary Deck on Anki, and the app Takoboto, plus Google translation) tell me that sakan is pronunced "sakau" with a "u" sound at the end ! I'm confused.

Is it really how this word is pronunced ? Or is it an error of translation ?

edit:

Acually, all the words finishing in -n that I've just tried on Google translation (konban, ichiban, nedan) finished with the sound "u" by the person speaking.

I wasn't aware this problem existed.

Comment: https://ja.forvo.com/search/%E7%9B%9B%E3%82%93/

Comment: It might be your ears. Japanese ん at the end of the word isn't a sound like English /n/, but a much farther back thing ([ɴ] in IPA). You might be hearing [ɴ] and your brain is reinterpreting it as something like [ũ].

Comment: It's a very interesting report that reminds me how Japanese reinterpreted Chinese [ŋ] to [ũ] back in the time there was no ん in Japanese.

Comment: Some are certainly weird, perhaps because of technical difficulty? https://translate.google.com/#ja/en/%E7%9B%9B%E3%82%93%E3%80%81%E4%BB%8A%E6%99%A9%E3%80%81%E4%B8%80%E7%95%AA%E3%80%81%E5%80%A4%E6%AE%B5

Answer (score 3):

The Japanese ん　can be a bit tricky because it is pronounced differentely depending on where it is located in the sentence.

I am not a linguist, so I cannot explain the behaviour using the appropriate terminology. As a rule of thumb, suffice it to say that ん will be vocalised when it is positioned at the end of a syllable or a word. Avoid pronouncing it like an English "n" in those instances!

To learn more about how you should pronounce ん, check out the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology#Moraic_nasal